# How do I close a single frame in Java?

Tags: java, awt, frame

So, I have a frame(awt) with a button, and if you click "Sync" it makes a popup. Right now, I simply want it so you can click the X on that popup, and the popup will go away. I have a comment showing where I want it to go away.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ActionListener listen=new MyActionListener();
        Frame frame= new Frame("frame");//make the frame
        Button exit=new Button("Exit");
        exit.setActionCommand("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(listen);
        Button Sync=new Button("Sync");
        Sync.setActionCommand("Sync");
        Sync.addActionListener(listen);//create Exit and Sync buttons.
        frame.add(exit);
        frame.add(Sync);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        frame.setSize(100,80);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
    public void MyActionListener(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String s = ae.getActionCommand();
        if (s.equals("Exit")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }//note that the exit button DOES work, so this system is working.
        if (s.equals("Sync")) {
            Frame frame2= new Frame("Popup!");
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
            {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                {
                    //Remove frame2 here.
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I saw a very similar (if not the same) question asked before, and the "answer" was to use dispose. ("frame2.dispose();")
I tried that, and i got the following error report:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - local variable frame2 is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
    at vexscouting.MyActionListener$1.windowClosing(Main.java:76)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:1865)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:1823)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Note: I'm using NetBeans

Comment: You're trying to run uncompilable code -- never do that. First fix the compilation issues, then and only then run the code. Either make frame2 variable final or make it a class field. Why are you using AWT components and not Swing components anyway? If this were a Swing application, you'd show the second window as a JDialog, and all would work well.

Comment: I only ran the uncompilable code to see exactly what it said. With netbeans I can run the uncompilable code and test the parts that do work(the above program is crippled so I can get my point across without tons of extra code). I'm fairly new to java btw. I'm kind of just playing with this, and I'm going to play a little with swing later.

Comment: Regardless if you *can* run uncompilable code, you really *shouldn't*. NetBeans or any decent IDE will tell you what compilation errors you may have and may even offer suggestions on how to fix them.